# Is there a card footer/ card deck feature on vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I want make like this : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-groups

[image]

So I want height of the box remains the same even though the description changes

My codepen like this :

https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/dyyWadg?editors=1010

```
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row dense>
      <v-col
        v-for="card in cards"
        :key="card.title"
        :cols="card.flex"
      >
        <v-card>
          <v-img
            :src="card.src"
            class="white--text align-end"
            gradient="to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
            height="200px"
          >

          </v-img>
          <v-card-text v-text="card.title"></v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>

            <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
            </v-btn>

            <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-bookmark</v-icon>
            </v-btn>

            <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-share-variant</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
```

I want the height card to remain the same, although the descriptions are different

How can I do it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with vuetify but `.theme--light.v-card { height: 100%;}` works

Answer (score 4):

The above code looks fine, just you need to add d-flex class to your columns inside row to have same height like other columns

working codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/ZEEKPaM?editors=1010

**Updated:** added fixes to move v-card action to bottom when flex card grows

```
    <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
      class="mx-auto"
      max-width="500"
    >
      <v-system-bar
        color="indigo darken-2"
        dark
      >
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>

        <v-icon>mdi-window-minimize</v-icon>

        <v-icon>mdi-window-maximize</v-icon>

        <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
      </v-system-bar>

      <v-toolbar
        color="indigo"
        dark
      >
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

        <v-toolbar-title>Discover</v-toolbar-title>

        <v-spacer></v-spacer>

        <v-btn icon>
          <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-toolbar>

      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row dense>
          <v-col
            v-for="card in cards"
            :key="card.title"
            :cols="card.flex"
            class="d-flex"
          >
            <v-card class="d-flex flex-column">
              <v-img
                :src="card.src"
                class="white--text align-end"
                gradient="to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
                height="200px"
              >

              </v-img>
              <v-card-text v-text="card.title"></v-card-text>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-card-actions>

                <v-btn icon>
                  <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
                </v-btn>

                <v-btn icon>
                  <v-icon>mdi-bookmark</v-icon>
                </v-btn>

                <v-btn icon>
                  <v-icon>mdi-share-variant</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    cards: [
      { title: 'Pre-fab homes aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/house.jpg', flex: 4 },
      { title: 'Favorite roaddddddddd', src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/road.jpg', flex: 4 },
      { title: 'Best airlines', src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/plane.jpg', flex: 4 },
    ],
  }),
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Vuetify supports flexbox https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex
So the only thing you've todo is to add `class="d-flex"` to your v-col

```
<v-container fluid>
    <v-row dense>
      <v-col
        v-for="card in cards"
        :key="card.title"
        :cols="card.flex"
        class="d-flex"
      >
        <v-card class="d-flex flex-column">
          <v-img
            :src="card.src"
            class="white--text align-end"
            gradient="to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.1), rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
            height="200px"
          >

          </v-img>
          <v-card-text v-text="card.title" class="flex-grow-1"></v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>

            <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
            </v-btn>

            <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-bookmark</v-icon>
            </v-btn>

            <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-share-variant</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
```

For aligning the content within the item correctly:

- Add `class="d-flex flex-column"` to `v-card`
- Add `class="flex-grow-1"` to your `v-card-text`
- Override styling form v-responsive (probably this could also be solved in a nicer way)

  ```
  .v-responsive {
    flex: unset;  
  }
  ```

https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/WNNjmJd